# Checking if a line in a file is obsolete, if yes then delete it

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've got a saved filed called records.txt on the phone. A line of it looks like this:

XY Family, **2015.11.10.** 12:12 2

Name of family, date, time and another number.

---

Now, when the user opens the app, I'd like to check this file, and if there's a date there, that is already passed, then delete that line from the text file.

My logic was, first copy the lines to an array of string, then check each one if the date is passed, and if not, copy those into a new array of string. Delete the text file and create a new one with the 2nd string array.

The funny thing is, my code works with windows forms, but fails on android. Here it is:

```
var path = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
var records = Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "records.txt");

string[] recordLines; // original lines
string[] newLines; // new lines, excluding the obsolete date lines
int counter = 0;

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(records))
    {
          try
          {
                recordLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(records);
                newLines = new string[recordLines.Length];

                foreach(string rl in recordLines)
                {
                      Regex mypattern = new Regex(@"Család, ([ ._0-9A-Za-z-]+) \w");
                      string recordDate = mypattern.Match(rl).Groups[1].Value;
                      DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(recordDate);

                      if (!((dt - DateTime.Today).TotalSeconds < 0))
                      {
                            newLines[counter] = rl;
                            counter++;
                      }
                 }

                 File.Delete(records);                    
                 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(records))
                 {
                       foreach(string s in newLines)
                       {
                             sw.WriteLine(s);
                       }
                 }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                  // tba
            }
    }
```

---

**EDIT:** It fails by not even touching the text file. I tried to create a new one, but it won't do that either. I assume that means something is wrong with the arrays.

I have set two permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**EDIT2:** Apparently my phone wrapped the line of the file, therefore making the regex unusable. I'm fixing it right now.

**EDIT3:** It was indeed the phone's saving problem, it wrapped the text unusable.

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions to delete?

Comment: It fails by not even touching the text file. I tried to create a new one, but it won't do that either. I assume that means something is wrong with the arrays. I have set two permissions: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: can you modify the way this line is entered? how are you going to extract the data? by searching for a `,`? what if the title includes one?

Comment: The title can't include one (there's a spinner already specified for the names). Found the problem, see the edits.